# Getting and exception NotSerializableException: com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl

Tags: hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-jet

I am new to hazelcast-jet and my use case is to read from Kafka source and filter after checking its value in hazelcastIMDG.

I am getting and loading IMDG map even before creating pipeline. See below

```
 IMap<String, Policy> policyMap =jet.getHazelcastInstance().getMap(POLICY_MAP_NAME);
            Utility.populatePoliciesMap(policyMap);
```

passing policyMap as param in the buildPipeline method.

i have created a pipeline as below

```
StreamStage<TimestampedEntry<String, Long>> streamStage = pipeline.drawFrom(KafkaSources.kafka(brokerConsumerProperties(), projectionFn, getIngestTopic()))
                .addTimestamps()
                .flatMap(ingestData -> traverseArray(ingestData.getMapRequestParameterTree().toArray(new String[ingestData.getMapRequestParameterTree().size()])))
                .filter(hash -> policyMap.get(hash)!=null)
                .window(sliding(MINUTES.toMillis(1), SECONDS.toMillis(10)))
                .groupingKey(wholeItem())
                .aggregate(counting())
               .map((TimestampedEntry<String, Long> e) -> entry(e.getKey(), createBlacklistObjectEvent(Utility.fetchPolicy(e.getKey()), e.getTimestamp(), e.getValue())));
        timestampedEntryStreamStage.drainTo(Sinks.map(BL_MAP_NAME));
```

but with this i am getting below exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   "filterFn" must be serializable   at
>   com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.Util.checkSerializable(Util.java:301)     at
>   com.hazelcast.jet.impl.pipeline.ComputeStageImplBase.attachFilter(ComputeStageImplBase.java:129)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.jet.impl.pipeline.StreamStageImpl.filter(StreamStageImpl.java:71)
>     at
>   com.visa.rls.handler.HazelcastJetIngetstResultHandler.buildPipeline(HazelcastJetIngetstResultHandler.java:120)
>     at
>   com.visa.rls.handler.HazelcastJetIngetstResultHandler.run(HazelcastJetIngetstResultHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   com.visa.rls.handler.HazelcastJetIngetstResultHandler.main(HazelcastJetIngetstResultHandler.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>     at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.util.Util.checkSerializable(Util.java:299)
>     ... 5 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `policyMap` inside the filter function, but the `IMap` isn't serializable. It gets captured by the lambda expression. You have to get the `IMap` instance on each remote member, for which you can use `filterUsingContext` instead of `filter`:

```java
.filterUsingContext(
    ContextFactory.withCreateFn(jetInstance -> jetInstance.getMap(POLICY_MAP_NAME)),
    (policyMap, hash) -> policyMap.get(hash) != null
)
```

Comment: thanks.  however i do have another question related to kafka streaming with jet.   how jet handle kafka auto commit property. I noticed it is by default set to false.

Comment: And i have another question related to sliding window(hazelcast-jet:0.7.2 release ). It returns TimestampedEntry which contain timestamp. I observed it is bucket timestamp not window timestamp. Is there a way to get the bucket timestamp and count in that bucket with in 0.7.2 release itself.    However i tried the latest snapshot version, notice it has KeyWindowResult class where end() method returns window end timestamp. will that released in upcoming release ? when is this release planned ?

Comment: One more question related to cluster formation. You provide multiple ways(multicast and tcp .. etc) to form a cluster. Can you provide us the example/sample code for both doing programmatically configuration and xml based configuration. my preferred way is to use TCP. Sorry for too many question and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hazelcast Jet 3.0 will be released in a few days. For the network configuration you can check the Hazelcast IMDG documentation 

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12/manual/html-single/index.html#understanding-configuration

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12/manual/html-single/index.html#setting-up-clusters